CSS stepped border - recreate design piece
I'm struggling to recreate a designed header from a poster in html/css.
I can get it to work as per the image, but it needs to have a transparent background so the image shows through. However, the dividing border appears as soon as I make the background transparent, which is not what I want.
Is there any way around this?

Image of header with solid background



html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: url(https://www.iwa.ie/app/themes/iwa-theme/resources/assets/img/sport/basketball/senior-league-main-hero.webp) 50% / cover;
}

.branded-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.brand-header-top {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 8px 20px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 37px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff
}

.brand-header-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  padding: 16px 19px 6px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 53px;
  background: #transparent;
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-family: CentraleSans, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 64px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="branded-header" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <div class="brand-header-top">
      Wheelchair Basketball
    </div>
    <div class="brand-header-bottom">
      Senior League 2024/2025
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Paulie_D if you give a background to body and remove backgrounds from header's element to see through, you will see every borders of these elements . part of it is unwanted :)

You should demonstrate your issue where we see that top border annoying you, your screenshot and snippet are confusing

@phuzi i think the op is trying something of that kind : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poMKbvz

Sorry the question is confusing, first time posting :(
I cant seem to edit the question to add the correct and incorrect images to show comparison
but here is a pen - I want to get rid of the border in the middle and still have the image showing through
Codepen

As commented , mix-blend-mode can help to achieve the desired result:
A black color with mix-blend-mode:screen will become transparent.
You basicly need to add this to your rules :
.branded-header {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.brand-header-top,
.brand-header-bottom {
  background: black;
}

Snippet made from your codepen and updated with previous CSS , to run to see the result


html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: url(https://www.iwa.ie/app/themes/iwa-theme/resources/assets/img/sport/basketball/senior-league-main-hero.webp) 50% / cover;
}
/* UPDATE FOR THE TRANSPARENCY */
.branded-header {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.brand-header-top,
.brand-header-bottom {
  background: black;
}

/* END UPDATE FOR THE TRANSPARENCY */
.branded-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.brand-header-top {/* do not set again background or just black */
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 8px 20px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 37px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.brand-header-bottom {/* do not set again background or just black */
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  padding: 16px 19px 6px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 53px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-family: CentraleSans, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 64px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="branded-header" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <div class="brand-header-top">
      Wheelchair Basketball
    </div>
    <div class="brand-header-bottom">
      Senior League 2024/2025
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Take a look at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode for more infos about mix-blend-mode
I posted in the comment this pen trying to show an average expected result https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poMKbvz using your brown background with exclusion , switching to a black background and screen makes it easy to achieve .

This a nice solution but I see artefacts at least on IOS at some zoom levels (a thin white line, I guess because of sort of rounding errors).

@AHaworth , yes, that kind of things always happens when zooming , i never really  mind it , such as pixel perfect

Thanks for the solution - works great!

Using a pseudo element with the same background image with background-attachment:fixed would do the trick:


html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: url(https://www.iwa.ie/app/themes/iwa-theme/resources/assets/img/sport/basketball/senior-league-main-hero.webp) fixed 50% / cover;
}

.branded-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.brand-header-top {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 8px 20px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 37px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff
}

.brand-header-top:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; z-index:-1;
  bottom: -8px; left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(https://www.iwa.ie/app/themes/iwa-theme/resources/assets/img/sport/basketball/senior-league-main-hero.webp) fixed 50% / cover;
}

.brand-header-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  padding: 16px 19px 6px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 53px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-family: CentraleSans, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 64px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="branded-header" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <div class="brand-header-top">
      Wheelchair Basketball
    </div>
    <div class="brand-header-bottom">
      Senior League 2024/2025
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




I’ve just tried this on IOS and, depending on the zoom level, see an artefact - a thin white line between the two sections. I guess because of a sort of rounding error when the system maps CSS pixels to screen ones.

@AHaworth, yes sir, subpixel rounding it is. But I have another idea: to use a pseudo-element to hide the border.

Be careful with the height of the pseudo element, if the text had some descenders it would overwrite them. Making it slightly less tall may solve this OK.

@AHaworth, negative z-index solves this
